# Where are the exception table entries for EL2 and EL3 on linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, kernel, arm64

At https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2734d6c1b1a089fb593ef6a23d4b70903526fe0c/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S#L497, linux defines the arm64 vector table:

```
SYM_CODE_START(vectors)
    kernel_ventry   1, t, 64, sync      // Synchronous EL1t
    kernel_ventry   1, t, 64, irq       // IRQ EL1t
    kernel_ventry   1, t, 64, fiq       // FIQ EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, t, 64, error     // Error EL1t

    kernel_ventry   1, h, 64, sync      // Synchronous EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, h, 64, irq       // IRQ EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, h, 64, fiq       // FIQ EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, h, 64, error     // Error EL1h

    kernel_ventry   0, t, 64, sync      // Synchronous 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 64, irq       // IRQ 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 64, fiq       // FIQ 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 64, error     // Error 64-bit EL0

    kernel_ventry   0, t, 32, sync      // Synchronous 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 32, irq       // IRQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 32, fiq       // FIQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, t, 32, error     // Error 32-bit EL0
SYM_CODE_END(vectors)
```

the macro `kernel_ventry` generates the handlers for each exception, I don't know where to find them but it looks like on the kernel v4.9 at least the entry 0 for sync would be `el0_sync`.

Anyways, where are the exception vector table entries for EL2 and EL3? According to https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100933/0100/AArch64-exception-vector-table?lang=en, the exception table should be a contiguous memory space with the exception vectors for all the 4 EL_ levels

Comment: To quote the document you linked: _"Each Exception level has its own vector table"_ and _"The base address is given by VBAR_ELn"_. So no, it does not say all 4 levels need to be contiguous. It specifically says you can set each level separately. EL2 seems to be `__hyp_stub_vectors`. EL3 does not seem to be used. Disclaimer: I am not an arm64 expert, I just did a quick search of the kernel source.

Comment: @Jester you should turn that into an answer. You can back up your findings by searching for [`vbar_el2`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=vbar_el2) and [`vbar_el3`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=vbar_el3) respectively.

Comment: @Jester I misinterpreted then. I thought that code I placed here was the table for EL0 and EL1 but it's actually EL1 with some entries when the exception is to be taken at a lower level. So the EL0 is somewhere else and EL2 is at `__hyp_stub_vectors`

Comment: why they are called stub by the way?

Comment: @Jester maybe you meant `__kvm_hyp_vector`? They're on another file

Comment: Might depend on kernel version. I have an old 5.0 source here.